# Is $H^i(X)$ a finite dmensional vector space when $X$ is an abstract non singular curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

The main problem is:

Is possible to see that a complete non singular abstract curve is projective using Riemann-Roch?

For abstract non singular curve i mean that $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a $k$ space of function $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ over a notherian irreducible space $X$ of dimension $1$, with all local rings $(\mathcal{O}_X)_x$ regular (for each point $x\in X$) that can be covered by $U_i$ ($i\in \bar{n}$) affine open sets (where $U_i$ is an affine open set iff $U_i\cong spec(A_i)$ where $A_i$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra without nilpotent).

Complete mean that is separable and that for any $k$-variety $Y$ the projection map from $X\times Y$ in $Y$ in closed under the Zariski topology of the product.

All the machinery using to prove the R-R seems lecit under this hypotesis exept the fact that $H^i(X)$ (that is isomorphic to the Check chomology) is a $k$ vector space of finite dimesion.

So the problem is: If $X$ is an abstract complete curve over an algebrically closed field $k$, is $H^i(X)$ a finite dimensional $k$ vector space?

Note: The Grothendieck vanishing theorem reduce the question at the case of $i=0$ and $i=1$.

Someone has any suggestion please?

Comment: This is true in general for complete varieties over a field $k$ (e.g. an abstract complete curve). The proof however, reduces to the case of projective varieties using Chow's lemma and then eventually to the case of $X=\mathbb{P}^n$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, sorry i can't see all the steps. Is the Chow' s lemma on a smooth curve equivalent to say that the curve is projective? And then i think that is the classical proof, but my indeed was to prove that is projective using R-R

Answer (score 2):

This might be overkill, but the following should work: a complete variety $\pi:X\to \operatorname{Spec} k$ for any field $k$ is proper, so the direct image and higher direct images of $\mathcal{O}_X$ are all coherent. But $R^i\pi_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is just $H^i(X)$, and since the coherent sheaves on $\operatorname{Spec} k$ are just the finite-dimensional vector spaces over $k$, we see that $H^i(X)$ is finite-dimensional for any complete variety over a field.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you give some more information about $R^i\pi_*\mathcal{O}_X\cong H^i(X)$ please?

Comment: Sure - the definition of $R^i\pi_*\mathcal{F}$ is that it's the sheaf associated to the presheaf $U\mapsto H^i(\pi^{-1}(U),\mathcal{F})$. Since the target is a point, there's no sheafification to be done, and the unique value of the sheaf is exactly $H^i(\pi^{-1}(\operatorname{Spec} k),\mathcal{O}_X)=H^i(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=H^i(X)$.

Comment: Perfect, i notice now that i also don't understand why $H^i(\pi^{-1}(U),\mathcal{F})$ is a choerent sheaf for $i>0$. Is that a general fact?

Comment: Yes, it's a general fact that the direct image and higher direct images of coherent sheaves along a proper map are coherent. See for instance EGA III Theoreme 3.2.1 or [Stacks](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02O3).

Comment: Doesn't the proof of this use Chow's Lemma to reduce to the projective case?

Comment: @user45878 Apparently so - I had forgotten that Chow's lemma was a portion of the proof.